# Cannot establish ssl connection with urllib or wget while browsers work fine

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to use python3 to log into a website. My code is below

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

login = urlencode({'user' : 'test', 'pass' : 'test', 'uuid' : ''}).encode('ascii')

rq = Request("https://novanet.villanova.edu/cp/home/login", data=login)

f = urlopen(rq, timeout=10)
ff = f.read()
fff = ff.decode("utf-8")
```

My problem is that there always is a timeout during the SSL handshake:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 317, in __init__
    raise x
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 313, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 520, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:531: The handshake operation timed out
```

If I don't enforce the 10s timeout, eventually the connection will be reset by peer.

I have no idea where I'm going wrong. However, when I try to `wget https://novanet.villanova.edu/cp/home/displaylogin`, which is where the site redirects to inside a browser I can't establish an SSL connection either. Opening the pages in a browser works fine though.

Is it my code? Is it the server? How can I work around this?

Comment: I can't login because of wrong credentials but your code works for mee (login failed)

Comment: @oleg no idea how that worked for you. 3.3.2 showed the same issue on both win7 and my linux box. VPNing into the network didn't help either. I always get a ssl handshake timeout ...

Comment: I check both python 2.7 and python 3.2.3